# Whats wrong with this junit test case?

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to setup tests using jUnit in my application. This is my first experience doing it.

Here is my test case:

```
public class TestClass 
{
    StudentDAO s= new StudentDAO();
    @Test
    public void testStudentsInQFG() 
    {
         Assert.assertEquals(s.getStudentCountFromDB("1"),10);
    }
}
```

Here is the Student DAO method:

```
public int getStudentCountFromDB(String CourseID)
{
    String sqlCount="SELECT Count(*) FROM  Student WHERE CourseID=?";
    return this.getMySQLJDBCTemplate().queryForObject(sqlCount,new Object[] {CourseID}, Integer.class);
}
```

The method returns the right results when I call it from my Main method but the fails when I use the assertEquals. Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.omnitracs.fra.dao.StudentDAO.testStudentsInQFG(StudentDAO.java:107)
 at com.omnitracs.fra.junit.TestClass.testStudents(TestClass.java:17)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Probably nothing to do with JUnit something in your studentDAO Class. Are you connected to the DB properly?

Comment: How does your application usually instantiate a `studentDAO`?  You'll really need to do it the same way.  Also - unrelated to your problem but worth fixing - your arguments to `assertEquals` are round the wrong way.

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't match your code.  It shows `testStudentsInQFG` as being in the `StudentDAO` class.  Are you sure that what you've posted is the code that you're actually running?

Comment: You should consider using a mocking library. You could mock the DB in your test.

Comment: @DavidWallace I had to change a few names to hide the actual names since the actual names are direct reflection of my industry terms and database names. the code is correct.

Comment: So presumably the first line of the stack trace should reference `StudentDAO.getStudentCountFromDB` and the second should reference `TestClass.testStudentsInQFG`, right?

Comment: I believe user2402781's answer is right.  It looks like `getMySQLJDBCTemplate()` is returning null, which suggests that you haven't initialised your `StudentDAO` properly.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes. I have accepted that as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when StudentDao is calling your method getMySQLJDBCTemplate(), this method returns null (or directly throws an exception because it tries to access to access a variable which is not yet initialized).

You probably have to call have a method like setMySQLJDBCTemplate(jdbcTemplate) in your DAO, with a correctly initialized jdbcTemplate or a Mock (you can have a look at the library Mockito for that). You need to call it first in your test, to set the mysql template, before trying to access the DB. You may need to initialize as well other fields of your DAO.

Comment: Yes, I did miss those in my Test Class. I added those lines and its working now.